# Can /etc/hosts config reverse resolution?

Tags: dns, hosts

As we all known, we can add 'ip host' item in /etc/hosts to mock a DNS's name resolution, now comes the question, can I use /etc/hosts to do inverse resolution, form ip to hostname? Or is there any other handy way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer is no, but I'm trying to figure out what you want from this. Do you have some sort of reverse DNS system that you want to override its result?

Comment: I just want a simple way to config reverse name resolution, just for a test project, donot want to config the DNS system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That can only be done on a DNS server.

Answer (score 34):

Maybe. It will depend on the tool you use to do the lookup and the configuration of resolving on your computer.

For example gethostbyaddr() will check /etc/hosts if "files" is in the hosts section of your /etc/nsswitch.conf

Note however that not all tools will do a local resolve, such as the "host" command for example, so it depends entirely on how you are attempting to do the lookup.

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: with `files` in nsswitch.conf I'm able to get reverse DNS record from /etc/hosts by:
    `getent hosts ip_here`

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It does that automatically if the application uses Name Service Switch libraries (most applications do), and if `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is configured to resolve IPs from `/etc/hosts` with a line such as this:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

You can test the reverse name resolution with either of the options below:

```
getent hosts 127.0.0.1
```

or

```
resolveip 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  If you use dnsmasq, you can interfere in a number of ways to get a forward lookup going to 127.0.0.1 and the reverse lookup from 127.0.0.1 going to your host.  For example, if your hostname is host1.mydomain.com with a real IP address of 192.168.1.12, then you can get 127.0.0.1 to resolve to it by doing the following in the dnsmasq configuration file:
host-record=host1.mydomain.com,127.0.0.1

The forward interference can be done in many ways, here is one:
alias=192.168.1.12,127.0.0.1

Obviously you need to set up the rest of dnsmasq properly to forward to your real DNS server ... but that is simple enough